# window.open not resizable, scrollable

Tags: javascript, window.open

I tried `window.open` and want the javascript to open a new browser with new url and wants the new window to be resizable and scrollable

i tried

```
window.open("someurl", '_blank','windowOpenTab', 'scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=1000,height=580,left=0, top=0');
```

**Edit1**: tried `window.open(url, '_blank','windowOpenTab', 'scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=1000,height=580,left=0,top=0');`
still no luck

read about window.open from http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml but no luck :(

Comment: you cannot have spaces in that last string

Comment: @Sergio - updated still the same :(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open) you can only have 3 parameters in that function.

```
window.open(strUrl, strWindowName[, strWindowFeatures]);
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dSKH9/1/)** - I droped the `'_blank'` and made a demo with small window just to make the scrollbar showup.

So you can use:

```
window.open("someurl", 'windowOpenTab', 'scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=1000,height=580,left=0,top=0');
```

Comment: i want to make sure it opens a new window always and there is never a case that it opens a new tab

Comment: @Varun, I'm not sure that is cross browser compat. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript

Comment: Watch how you're spelling resizable, I got caught out for a head-banging 10 minutes by misspelling it resizeable.

Comment: In my case, I had to use this and add <html style="overflow-y: scroll;"> to force the scroll bar on the pop-up window. as @Bob said, watch out with spelling "resizeable"

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 window.open("someurl", '_blank','windowOpenTab', 'scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=1000,height=580,left=0, top=0');
```

to

```
 window.open("someurl", 'windowOpenTab', 'scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=1000,height=580,left=0, top=0');
```

Just remove the **_blank**, [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t3vkK/).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 function openPopupWindow(){ 
window.open("http://example.com","popup","width=668,height=548,scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes");     
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/LtKVQ/)

```
popupWin = window.open('http://webdesign.about.com/',
'open_window','menubar, toolbar, location, directories, status, scrollbars, resizable,
dependent, width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0')
```